# odds ratio to relative risk equation, how is it derived?

Tags: odds-ratio, relative-risk

How is this equation derived? thanks

RR=OR/((1−Pref)+(Pref∗OR))

RR = risk ratio; OR = odds ratio;
Pref = Prevalence of the outcome in the reference group

Answer (score 0):

Relative Risk

```
RR = p1/p0
```

Odds Ratio

```
OR = (p1/(1-p1)) * ((1-p0)/p0)

OR * (p0/(1-p0)) = p1/(1-p1) 

(1-p0)/(OR*p0) = (1-p1)/p1

(1-p0)/(OR*p0) = 1/p1 - 1

1 + (1-p0)/(OR*p0) = 1/p1

(OR*p0+(1-p0))/(OR*p0) = 1/p1

(OR*p0)/(OR*p0+(1-p0)) = p1

p1 = (OR*p0)/(OR*p0+(1-p0))
```

Since RR = p1/p0

```
p1 = (OR*p0)/(OR*p0+(1-p0))

p1/p0 = (OR*p0)/((OR*p0+(1-p0))*p0)

p1/p0 = OR / OR*p0+(1-p0)
```

which means:

```
RR = OR / ((1-p0)+(OR*p0))
```

RR = risk ratio; OR = odds ratio; p1 = the outcome in the experiment/exposed group; p0 = the outcome in the reference group